# Specify date format of a large amount of input data

Tags: vba, excel

I have an input spreadsheet that needs to get sorted by date.  The current format of the date is in the UK format (dd/mm/yyyy) but I need it in yyyy-mm-dd (actually I don't, I just need to sort it and that format is the most foolproof way of sorting).  This all needs to be done in VBA as it's part of a bigger project that allows a bunch of data collation at once.  The other problem is that the input sheet can be quite large (150,000+ rows).  So, while I *could* parse through each row of data and change it around to the way I need, this would be horrifically slow and is NOT an option.

Currently I'm using this bit of code to format the date to yyyy-mm-dd:

```
inputGADRSheet.Columns(7).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

But, Excel outsmarts me and assumes that the date format of the column is originally in the US format (mm/dd/yyyy) which messes everything up and half of the values in the column don't meet that requirement (days above the 12th) so they don't get formatted at all. Is there any way to tell Excel what format the current data is in? That way it won't just assume that it's in the US date format...

Is the solution to change my Excel region to the UK.  I assume this could be done using VBA, but it seems risky...

Comment: AFAIK, cell format has NO impact on sorting dates (or any kind of number). I suspect your "dates" are indeed Strings. So the real question is "how do I convert String into dates", and I am quite sure it's already somewhere in SO.

Comment: I think you're right about the dates being strings instead of actual dates.  So the problem becomes how do quickly convert these strings to dates for 150,000+ rows...

Comment: Ugh... this is such a pain.  So, I've done a bit more digging based on the two comments and I've found that once the sheet is first opened Excel will format anything that looks like a date (in the US format) as a date.  Anything that does not qualify will be left as a string value.  So, I actually have a mix of dates and string in that column.  The dates are all wrong however since Excel was trying to apply them to the US standard instead of the UK standard date format.  I'm sure the developer was British, which is why it worked OK when he did his testing. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is already in an Excel column, you can't reinterpret the values: Excel date values are (internally) number, `1` representing 1900-01-01. After the data has been (mis-)interpreted by Excel there's no way back.

The question is: Where do you get the input data sheet from? If the dates are entered correctly, reformatting is possible without any problem and does not affect sorting (which depends only on the numeric value of the date). If your data comes from a text file (probably .csv-kind), be sure to read ii as text and use Excel worksheet functions or VBA to interpret the values.

Comment: The data sheet comes from an external application that accesses a database.  The output from this application is an Excel sheet (rather than .csv).  Oddly the application itself has the date formatted as dd-mmm-yyyy, but when you export the data it puts it in the form dd/mm/yyyy.  I'm thinking whoever wrote the export bit of the application didn't correctly format the columns when it gets exported. I.e. they didn't tell Excel that the column was a date, they just put some string text in the column and the Excel makes a best guess scenario when the user opens the sheet.

Comment: I depends on how the excel sheet is created. I tried to re-create the problem here by manually editing the contents of an OOXML file, but did not succeed: Text cells will not be interpreted as dates on re-opening the file, no matter if their content 'looks' like a date or not, as expected. If you have OOXML (`.xlsx`) too, you could easily take a look inside the track the error down.